# I want to count entries in each column of dataframe

Tags: r

I am currently understanding to use R for data cleaning and arranging purposes. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Id    Shopping_date_1    Shopping_date_2    Shopping_date_3
1     01/05/2018         01/25/2018         NA
2     02/06/2019         NA                 NA
3     08/05/2018         NA                 01/04/2019
```

I want to arrange the dataframe such that i get a column that can count number of times a user has shopped something like this:

```
Id    Shopping_date_1    Shopping_date_2    Shopping_date_3    Shop_count
1     01/05/2018         01/25/2018         NA                 2
2     02/06/2019         NA                 NA                 1
3     08/05/2018         NA                 01/04/2019         2
```

Please help!

Comment: Related: [R: count NAs per row in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801338/r-count-nas-per-row-in-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
rowSums(!is.na(df[, 2:length(df)]))

[1] 2 1 2
```