# R - How to drop rows with certain % of empty cells?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have a large dataframe and would like to drop any rows where 20% of the cells are empty. I can't seem to find a code to do this efficiently.

Comment: If you can find the number missing in a row, you can easily find the percentage, so I guess something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801338/r-count-nas-per-row-in-dataframe would be super helpful

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add sample data that makes your problem / question fully reproducible. Are your columns numeric or character? how many columns / rows is your data? Give us more information, and we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a lot of information, I think you can solve it with the help of `data.table`. See `?data.table` for more information.

```
library(data.table)

# make a reproducible example    
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1), 500, TRUE, prob = c(0.78, 0.22)), 
                 ncol = 50))
```

Apply a function that finds how many non-NA values there are per row, compare them to the maximum allowed and return only those columns that match:

```
dt[, test := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))) > .2*50,][test == TRUE, ]
```

Comment: Replace `sum(!is.na(x)) > .2*50` with `mean(!is.na(x)) > 0.2`

Comment: In my sample data all values are either 1 or NA, so `mean` would work. However, in a more general case the values will be different and it won't hold.

Answer (score 0):

With `map` and `dplyr` you could try this:

df:

```
df <- tibble(id = sequence(6), 
             var1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "x", "x", "X"), 
             var2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "x", "x", "X"), 
             var3 = c(NA, "Y", NA, "x", "x", "X"), 
             var4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "x", "x", "X"))
```

Then nest and calculate the perc_na in each row and filter those out:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  nest(-id) %>% 
  mutate(
    perc_na = map_dbl(data, ~ sum(is.na(.x)) / ncol(.x))
  ) %>% 
  filter(perc_na <= 0.8) %>% 
  select(-perc_na) %>% 
  unnest()
```