# Longitudinal exclusion of participants in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling, longitudinal

I have a large dataset in wide format where I have 9 waves of data from different timepoints (w1, w2, w3...) and an ID column. I want to exclude participants who only have data on 1 timepoint or 0 timepoints.
Earlier, I have excluded participants conditionally with the following code:

```
Result <- Merged[!(Merged$w1exclude >1),]
```

However, I am unsure how to adapt the code to include the w1-w9 variables on the condition that 9 or 8 of them have NA's.

This is my first post here and I am new to R so apologies if this has been answered in a thread elsewhere I am now aware of.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is potentially the same as  [Count NAs per row in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801338/count-nas-per-row-in-dataframe)

```
df <- data.frame(w1 = c(1,2,3,4,NA),
                 w2 = c(2,3,NA,4,NA))
rowSums(is.na(df))

[1] 0 0 1 0 2
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I had other variables in the dataset which needed imputing before I could count the NA's per row, but everything is solved now :)